# Average school levels

Tags: excel

I am currently creating a spreadsheet which has the results from examinations for KS3 students. The grades are:

```
2C
2B
2A
3C
3B
3A etc. ... up to 8A
```

There are six examinations and students will have a result from each.

How could I create a formula to average all of the grades from the examinations and obtain an overall average level?

Comment: Assign consecutive numbers (unless you want the average weighted in some way) to each grade (a LOOKUP table). Transform the students' grade to those numbers (use VLOOKUP on that table). use the AVERAGE function, transform back to a grade using the original table in reverse.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. However I'm not to sure how to do this. I have a table with the grade and corosponing number. How would I make the number match the grade? Thanks

Comment: Once you have the `AVERAGE` you can round to the nearest whole number and use `INDEX/MATCH` to get the corresponding grade, e.g. assuming you get the individual numeric grades in `Z2:Z10` then you can use this formula `=INDEX(grades,MATCH(ROUND(AVERAGE(Z2:Z10),0),numbers,0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the approach mentioned by @Bathsheba and refinement from @barry houdini:

Create a table_array as shown in L2:M20 in the image. I named that `Dict` and L2:L20 `Dalph`, M2:M20 `Denum`.

[image: SO19183088 example]

The formulae are:

In B10 copied across and down to G13:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Dict,2,0)
```

in H10 copied down to H13:

```
=ROUND(AVERAGE(B10:G10),0)
```

in H2 copied down to H5:

```
=INDEX(Dalph,MATCH(H10,Denum,0))
```

Assumes the requirement is by student.